# Not able to open VBA editor in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to open VBA editor from my Outlook. It suddenly stopped working. I already tried possible ways.

1. (From Shortcut) Alt+F11 - Not working, no error is coming.
2. (From Menu) Developer Tab -> Visual Basic Icon. Not working, no error is coming.

I am using Outlook 2013.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you try restarting Outlook ? Close it from Task Manager and Restart.

Comment: Close Outlook and remove from your RAM using your Task Manager. Try opening Outlook again and opening VBE. If problem still exists try a restart, and even still a complete reinstall.

Comment: yes I restarted my computer but still it is not working.

Comment: @lalit you might have to try a good 'ol fashion re-install

Comment: I have unsaved macros, there is any way by which I can get the macros I have written?

Comment: You can export them to your local and you will be able to import them again.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to repair Outlook/Office. Also, make sure F-like buttons are not disabled on the keyboard.

See [How to use Outlook's VBA Editor](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/).